# Python: best way to iterate through lists and store which has max value for each index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, iteration

In Python (3.8), I have 15 lists of the same length.

Each list contains floats.

Here for the example, I will pretend I have 3 lists of length 5 to demonstrate my problem:

```
List1 = [29.561801, 29.564141, 29.566480, 29.293966, 29.291252]
List2 = [26.602566, 22.752335, 22.755249, 22.754278, 22.756220]
List3 = [23.966560, 23.960471, 23.954381, 29.568819, 29.571159]
```

For each index, I want to find which list has the maximum value. And store the result in a new List. With my 3 example list from above, my output would be:

```
Result=[1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
```

Right now I have the following code to do this. It works, but it feels very tedious (especially since I have in reality 15 lists and not 3!).

```
maxValue = 0
listWithMaxValue=0
Result=[]
for i in range(len(List1)):
    maxValue=List1[i]
    listWithMaxValue=1
    if(List2[i] > maxValue):
        maxValue=List2[i]
        listWithMaxValue=2
    if(List3[i] > maxValue):
        maxValue=List3[i]
        listWithMaxValue=3
    Result=np.append(Result, listWithMaxValue)
```

It feels that there must be a better way to achieve the same result without repeating 15 times the same "if" loop?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of expected inputs and outputs. Where are you adding to any new list? Why are you taking the max of a single value?

Comment: So List1, List2, etc are those 15 lists of floats? And thus List1[i] is a float and you want us to believe that your code with max(List1[i]) "works"?

Comment: So each index correspond to a second of time, and each list is a temperature sensor. I need to know at each instant which sensor give me the highest temperature. I edit my comment to display input/output. I'm not in front of the computer that have the program today (computer which don't have internet) so I rewrote from memory the code, I did a mistake I edited it.

Comment: Code like `if List3[i] > maxValue` is very tedious indeed. Use the builtin function [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) to find the maximum rather than comparing all the values manually by yourself.

Comment: Could you be more specific in how I need to use it for my problem please?

Comment: If you refactor your data so that the first column looks like this: `Column1 = [29.561801, 26.602566, 23.966560]`, then the max value is `max_value = max(Column1)` and its position is `Column1.index(max_value)`. A quick and dirty solution though. The @tripleee solution is "more correct".

Comment: oh ok thanks. It seems that there is something not right with his solution it doesn't give the expected result..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having variables `List1`, `List2`, `List3` (presumably etc) is definitely a complication. You should have a single array and loop over its indices. Then the rest should be fairly trivial.

```
floats = [
  [1.0] * 7,
  [2.0] * 7,
  [3.0] * 7,
  [4.0] * 7,
  [17.42] * 7,
  [6.0] * 7,
  [0.1, 12.2, 27.3, 18.4, 496.5, 7.6, 1.7]]

maxidx = []

for i in range(len(floats[0])):
    maxx = floats[0][i]
    maxi = 0
    for x in range(len(floats)):
        f = floats[x][i]
        if f > maxx:
            maxx = f
            maxi = x
    maxidx.append(maxi)
```

This extracts the lowest-numbered index in the cases where there is a tie.

(For brevity, this only uses 7 lists of length 7; but it should be obvious that the logic extends to any dimensions.)

Because Python's variables are always references, you can actually build the outer array as a list of references to your existing variables if refactoring your current code seems like an excessive change.

```
floats = [List1, List2, List3, ...]
```

Array indices in Python are zero-based, so index 0 in the result means `List1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your code but I did not get the right output. For example if I modify your lists to have length of 3, I still receive an output list of length 7. Btw I modified my question to be more clear if you want

Comment: Sorry about that; see updated code now.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for your time it was exactly what I was wondering if I could have, I really appreciate thanks.

Comment: PS I'm not familiar with the site, but my question is still marked "closed" for "details needed", even if I did modify it and it seems comments work again... So my account seems to be locked now even if the question is now clear and been answered.. I don't find what to do next to fix..

Comment: Your account will not be barred from posting more questions because of a single bad post. Your other questions all seem well-received so either you have many bad deleted questions, or I misunderstand what you mean by "locked".

Answer (score 3):

Put all of your lists into a single list. You can then manage the sublists in terms of "columns" using zip.

Like this:

```
List1 = [29.561801, 29.564141, 29.566480, 29.293966, 29.291252]
List2 = [26.602566, 22.752335, 22.755249, 22.754278, 22.756220]
List3 = [23.966560, 23.960471, 23.954381, 29.568819, 29.571159]

lists = [List1, List2, List3]

result = [c.index(max(c))+1 for c in zip(*lists)]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
```

**Note:**

Python list indexes are zero-based but it appears that the requirement is for 1-based indexing hence the addition

Comment: Thanks I already accepted an answer above, but this seems to be even more efficient!